# Error when closing form 2 on C# application - NullReferenceException was unhandled

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to refresh my datagrid on `Form1` each time `Form2` is closed, but keep getting following error message: `NullReferenceException was handled. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` This happens at the line `Form1Instance.RefreshGridView();` on `Form2`. Any idea how I can resolve this? My code below:

**Form1.cs**

```
    public void RefreshGridView()
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

**Form2.cs**

```
    private Form1 Form1Instance
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Form2(Form1 form1Instance)
    {
        Form1Instance = form1Instance;
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1Instance.RefreshGridView();
    }
```

**Exception Detail**

`System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=PGPTool
  StackTrace:
       at PGPTool.Form2.Form2_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Antoine\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PGPTool\PGPTool\Form2.cs:line 104
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, Int32 wparam, Int32 lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Close()
       at PGPTool.Form2.save_btn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Antoine\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PGPTool\PGPTool\Form2.cs:line 78
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at PGPTool.Program.Main() in c:\users\Antoine\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PGPTool\PGPTool\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:`

Comment: How do you create `Form2` instance?

Comment: You should name your forms.

Comment: And what does the stack trace for the exception look like? That should show you where to find the problem.

Comment: And what does line 104 of Form2.cs look like?

Comment: Its `Form1Instance.RefreshGridView();`

Comment: Remove the default constructor in Form2, it is getting you into trouble.

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using FormClosed event try to handle [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *When a form is closed, it is disposed, releasing all resources associated with the form.*

So in Form.Closed event your Form1 instance Disposed. You are trying to access a Disposed element.

And you don't need to pass your Form1 instance to your Form2 constructor.When showing Form2 from Form1 you can simply do this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show(this);
```

Then you can access Form1 from Form2 like this:

```
((Form1)Owner).RefreshGridView();
```

Owner represents your parent form which is Form1

Comment: Owner is of type `Form`, so I don't think you could call `Owner.RefreshGridView();`

Answer (score 1):

In this example the error is comping from the fact that `Form1Instance` must be null.

Try checking if `Form1Instance` is actually set to a value before refreshing the datasource.

Example.

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if(Form1Instance != null)
        Form1Instance.RefreshGridView();
}
```

Comment: Don't hide bugs.  Use `throw new InvalidOperationException("You used the wrong constructor!");`

Comment: Nothing happens - the datagridview doesn't refresh

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier that is correct. If the Form1Instance is null (as the exception states) then the method wont be called. Can you show the code that actually sets the Form1Instance property?

Answer (score 0):

As @Selman22 indicated, you should make the call to the parent form when you handle the form closing event. You could also fire your own event and handle it in the parent form.